# LaTex text alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, text

I have a math equation `$$P(N) = \frac{N!}{(n_r)!(n_l)!} \cdot p_l^{n_r} \cdot p_r^{n_l}$$`and I want to label this equation as equation number 1. I tried to type `\hfill Eq 1.1` inside the equation, which looks something like this `$$P(N) = \frac{N!}{(n_r)!(n_l)!} \cdot p_l^{n_r} \cdot p_r^{n_l} \hfill{\text{Eq 1.1}} $$`. This doesn't seem to work. Is there any easier way to do this or how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you provide a complete, minimal working example including ` \documentclass{...}`? 
And why aren't you using the `equation`  environment, which provides numbering as default?

Comment: What is the equation environment; just started using latex today

Comment: The equation environment is an environment to typeset equations, as the name says. I'd suggest you check out some latex (maths) tutorials to find explanations of what you can do in latex.

Comment: you should never number anything "by hand", latex will number it for you (and also if you just started where did you see `$$` ? If it is in a tutorial somewhere we should get that fixed as it is not latex syntax).  Just use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` and the numbering will be automatic. (the exact numbering style, 1 or 1.1 or A can be controlled as document class settings, worry about that later)

Comment: I am very used to using MathJax from physics and math SE and was told that the syntax was the same for laTex. I will learn about equation mode

Comment: @Sumant the syntax is the same, more or less:-), `$$` does work in both but it's a lower level syntax which is not really supposed to be used in latex (and is not enabled by default in mathjax, although it is in the mathjax customisation in math SE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\usepackage{amsmath}`. Equation environments are `equation`(only one line) or `align`.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
P(N) = \frac{N!}{(n_r)!(n_l)!} \cdot p_l^{n_r} \cdot p_r^{n_l} \\
P(N) = \frac{N!}{(n_r)!(n_l)!} \cdot p_l^{n_r} \cdot p_r^{n_l}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
P(N) = \frac{N!}{(n_r)!(n_l)!} \cdot p_l^{n_r} \cdot p_r^{n_l}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```